# Update an indexed column with a constant

Tags: sql, database-schema

I have a table with primary key and indexed column.

- Initially with one operation, I do insertion based on primary key. And Indexed column has unique value. It is fine.
- The second operation is that I search line with this indexed column.
- The third operation I update the line based on primary key but set index column with a constant.

Is third operation updation slow according to the theory? I gave indexed column with the primary key, it does not help so much. Could someone point me why?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you are asking whether adding an index on the column you are changing will make your "update" faster.  The answer to this is no, indeed it will actually make it slower.

An update operation may be sped up if you can locate the row using the index faster than using the clustered index, which outweighs the cost (possibly) of updating the clustered index and the additional index on the table.

In your instance, as you are updating via the primary key, you cannot really optimise this further without using a technique to allow parallel operations on the primary index (partitioning the table in MS SQL Server).